# Unexpected behavior of complicated expression with increments and logical operators

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators

I was going through a C objective book where a question comes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    i=j=k=1;
    k=++i||++j&&++k;
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2 1 1
```

In my view:

1. `k` is incremented.
2. `j` is incremented.
3. `i` is incremented.
4. `k&&j` will happen.
5. `i|| (k&&j)`

So the output should be `i=2`,`j=2`,`k=1`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `k=++i||++j&&++k;` causes undefined behaviour.  You are trying to assign to `k` twice without an intervening sequence point.

Even if the assignment were to a different variable, your steps would be inaccurate - the logical operators have short-circuiting behaviour.

Edit:  OP says he changed the expression to `a=++i||++j&&++k`.  I'm going to rewrite it fully parenthesized and with some spaces:

```
a = ++i || (++j && ++k);
```

In this case, only the `++i` is evaluated, due to short-circuiting behaviour of the `||` operator.

Comment: (Also, if a programming book invokes undefined behavior, and doesn't state that it's undefined behavior, you should probably get a different book)

Comment: was my logic wrong if we don't go to undefined behaviour..

Comment: @migrenda, yes, your logic is still wrong, even in the absence of the UB in this case.

Comment: I changed k to a(a=++i||++j&&++k)

Comment: out put is still 2 1 1

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?  `++j&&++k` is never executed due to short-circuiting.

Comment: i have checked the precedence table and postfix is given higher priority in left to right sequence so maybe the leftmost (i.e k) will be evaluated first. According to you ++i will be done, then OR will be skipped and then AND operation will be done.

Comment: I think you'd better read more about how operator precedence and short-circuiting works in C.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37209/discussion-between-mrigendra-and-carl-norum)